# How can I create n divs, n coming from data in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This code doesnt create 4 divs. It just creates a div with 4 in it. How can I create divs by getting the number from data?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="n in number" :key="n">
      {{n}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return{
      number: 4
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-for` can most certainly range over integers: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range

Here is your `div` example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/l7lr4q6qoz

If your version doesn't work your problem lies elsewhere, not with `v-for="n in 5"`.